# gstreamer-1.0 :: Grabbing video stream from H264 ip camera and dumping it to a video

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

What would be an equivalent **gstreamer-1.0** command for:

```
ffmpeg -i <cam-url> -vcodec copy /tmp/h264Vid.avi
```

Here camera is giving H264 stream and we want to dump it directly to a video via gstreamer (do no need decoded data).

Comment: What is the OS you're running on? Can you give example of <cam-url>?

Comment: Hi, I am running Linux, CentOS7 to be specific.
Cam url: `rtsp://<user>:<pass>@<ip>/h264.sdp`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to record your rtsp camera stream, this should work:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location=rtsp://<user>:<pass>@<ip>/h264.sdp \
    ! video/x-h264 ! avimux \
    ! filesink location=video_test.avi
```